# What is the easiest way of finding the characters of a string after the last occurrence of a given character in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the easiest way of returning the substring consisting of the characters of a string after the last occurrence of a given character in Python.

Example:

```
s = 'foo-bar-123-7-foo2'
```

I am interested in the characters after the last occurrence of '-'.

So the output would be 'foo2'

I could do a str.find(sub,start,end) function to find the position of the first  '-' then store it's position then repeat this starting at this position to search for the next one until there are no more then return the characters of the string after this last position but is their a nicer way?

Comment: `s.split('-')[-1]`

Comment: Or maybe `re.sub(r'^.*-', '', s)`

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Brilliant, feel free to post this as an answer and I will mark as accepted!

Comment: @user9940344 RomanPerekhrest's answer is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with [`str.rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) function (returns the *highest* index in the string where substring is found):

```
s = 'foo-bar-123-7-foo2'
res = s[s.rfind('-') + 1:]
print(res)  # foo2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
s = 'foo-bar-123-7-foo2'
print(s.rsplit('-', 1)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

use [rfind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind)

so, `s.rfind('-')` will return you `13`, which is the last occurrence of '-'.
and further doing
`s[s.rfind('-')+1:]` will return `foo2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex option:

```
s = 'foo-bar-123-7-foo2'
output = re.sub(r'^.*-', '', s)
print(output)
```

This prints: `foo2`

The strategy here to match all content up, to and including, the final dash character.  Then, replace that with empty string, leaving only the final portion.